# Use a calculated field in the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00904

Is there a way to use a calculated field in the `where` clause?

I want to do something like

```
SELECT a, b, a+b as TOTAL FROM (
   select 7 as a, 8 as b FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   select 8 as a, 8 as b FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   select 0 as a, 0 as b FROM DUAL
)
WHERE TOTAL <> 0
;
```

but I get `ORA-00904: "TOTAL": invalid identifier`.

So I have to use

```
SELECT a, b, a+b as TOTAL FROM (
   select 7 as a, 8 as b FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   select 8 as a, 8 as b FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
   select 0 as a, 0 as b FROM DUAL
)
WHERE a+b <> 0
;
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

*Logically*, the `select` clause is one of the last parts of a query evaluated, so the aliases and derived columns are not available. (Except to `order by`, which *logically* happens last.)

Using a derived table is away around this:

```
select * 
from (SELECT a, b, a+b as TOTAL FROM ( 
           select 7 as a, 8 as b FROM DUAL 
           UNION ALL 
           select 8 as a, 8 as b FROM DUAL 
           UNION ALL 
           select 0 as a, 0 as b FROM DUAL) 
    )
WHERE TOTAL <> 0 
;
```

Comment: I was trying this in a Stored Procedure and the above syntax would not work unless I aliased the derived table as well.

Comment: @DilbertDave, interesting. Were you trying in Oracle? If I remember correctly, SQL Server always required derived tables to be aliased.

Comment: OP was asking about Oracle which doesn't need the alias. I'm glad this answer was able to help you even though it was for a different platform.

Comment: Ah - just noticed the Oracle error message and tags *blush*. Still, it pointed me in the right direction so upvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will work...

```
select * 
from (SELECT a, b, a+b as TOTAL FROM ( 
           select 7 as a, 8 as b FROM DUAL 
           UNION ALL 
           select 8 as a, 8 as b FROM DUAL 
           UNION ALL 
           select 0 as a, 0 as b FROM DUAL) 
    ) as Temp
WHERE TOTAL <> 0;
```

Comment: This answer is useful because of the additional `as Temp` which names the inner query.   That is important for it to execute, at least in SQL Server.