# Oracle - Possible to use alias in sum function?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

```
SELECT c.customer_name,
        sc.customer_id,
        SUM(
                (nvl(sc.year_1_new, 0) + nvl(sc.year_2_new, 0) + nvl(sc.year_3_new, 0) + 
                nvl(sc.year_4_new, 0) + nvl(sc.year_5_new, 0)) * sc.suggested_net
            ) AS ttl_new,
        SUM(
                (nvl(sc.year_1_nl, 0) + nvl(sc.year_2_nl, 0) + nvl(sc.year_3_nl, 0) + 
                nvl(sc.year_4_nl, 0) + nvl(sc.year_5_nl, 0)) * sc.suggested_net
            ) AS ttl_exist,
        SUM(ttl_new - ttl_exist) AS ttl_delta
FROM scenario_customers sc,
        customers c
WHERE sc.scenario_id = 10
        AND sc.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY sc.customer_id,
        c.customer_name
ORDER BY c.customer_name
```

I'd like to be able to subtract the ttl_new col from the ttl_exist col, and I'm getting an error, when I use the dynamic names, but if just paste the entire contents of the two sum functions into the 3rd sum function it works. So just wondering if this is possible, it'd certainly be easier to read.

**This is for Oracle 8i**

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is a way to use a calculated field in the where clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884678/there-is-a-way-to-use-a-calculated-field-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: In SQL, the entire select clause is evaluated, logically, at the same time. The query optimizer has to pick a particular ordering to do the evaluation, but the results must happen _as if_ all columns had been calculated at once. Thus the input from any one column will not available in any other column.

Comment: Having thought about it a bit, I don't think this question is an exact duplicate of the question linked. The solution is the same, to use an inline view, but the reasons are different. Logical order of different clauses, versus logical order within the `select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The scoping rules of most databases do not allow you to use the aliased names in the same SELECT statement.  You can do so using a subquery:

```
select c.customer_name, sc.customer_id, ttl_new, ttl_exist, (ttl_new - ttl_exist) as ttl_delta
from (SELECT c.customer_name, sc.customer_id,
             SUM((nvl(sc.year_1_new, 0) + nvl(sc.year_2_new, 0) + nvl(sc.year_3_new, 0)  + nvl(sc.year_4_new, 0)  + nvl(sc.year_5_new, 0)) * sc.suggested_net) AS ttl_new, 
             SUM((nvl(sc.year_1_nl, 0) + nvl(sc.year_2_nl, 0) + nvl(sc.year_3_nl, 0) + nvl(sc.year_4_nl, 0) + nvl(sc.year_5_nl, 0)) * sc.suggested_net) AS ttl_exist
      FROM scenario_customers sc join
           customers c
           on sc.customer_id = c.customer_id
      WHERE sc.scenario_id = 10 
      GROUP BY sc.customer_id, c.customer_name
     ) t
ORDER BY c.customer_name
```

I also fixed your join syntax.